# How to see vscode indexing progress

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to see indexing progress?

When I check out another branch or pull a lot of updates, install a new version of the npm package, vscode suggestions are not working, for example, vscode is not suggesting new enums from the file until i open the file manually.

In Webstorm there is a project indexing indicator right after git pull or npm install commands etc.

Thanks